# Can't find the .so while trying to build an rpm for php pecl extension module (geoip)

Tags: php, pear, pecl, geoip

I'm trying to make an RPM for easy deployment of the geoip php module on AWS machines. The RPM, along with others, will be hosted on a private repo only accessible to these machines. This is a requirement of a software I'm using so let's leave it at *I need it*.

My first attempt was

```
$ pecl makerpm geoip
WARNING: "pear makerpm" is no longer available; an improved version is available via "pear make-rpm-spec", which is available by installing PEAR_Command_Packaging
```

Fair enough, let's install this `PEAR_Command_Packaging` deal and continue...

```
$ pecl install PEAR_Command_Packaging
No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/PEAR_Command_Packaging"
install failed
```

OK, I could swear I was told to install this, but let's try `pear`:

```
$ pear install PEAR_Command_Packaging
Failed to download pear/PEAR_Command_Packaging within preferred state "stable", latest release is version 0.3.0, stability "alpha", use "channel://pear.php.net/PEAR_Command_Packaging-0.3.0" to install
install failed
```

Stability *alpha* hmm ... ok, let's see how active they are!
According to [their site](https://pear.php.net/package/PEAR_Command_Packaging) the project is not active and the last activity was in *April 2012* ... that won't do.

With that avenue closed, I look at the `pecl` command itself, which seems to offer *download*, *build*, and *install*. I don't want `install` because I'm only making the RPM here, but `download` and `build` sure look handy:

```
$ pecl download geoip-1.0.8
downloading geoip-1.0.8.tgz ...
Starting to download geoip-1.0.8.tgz (10,061 bytes)
.....done: 10,061 bytes
File /home/user/workspace/geoip-rpm-spec/geoip-1.0.8.tgz downloaded
```

Prep it for building ...

```
$ pecl bundle geoip
downloading geoip-1.0.8.tgz ...
Starting to download geoip-1.0.8.tgz (10,061 bytes)
.....done: 10,061 bytes
Package ready at '/home/user/workspace/geoip-rpm-spec/geoip'
```

Now, we build!

```
$ pecl build geoip/package.xml 
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20131106
Zend Module Api No:      20131226
Zend Extension Api No:   220131226
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-userttUJNa/geoip-1.0.8
... <snip/>
running: find "/var/tmp/pear-build-userttUJNa/install-geoip-1.0.8" | xargs ls -dils
264791  4 drwxrwxr-x 3 user user  4096 Oct  1 18:33 /var/tmp/pear-build-userttUJNa/install-geoip-1.0.8
265361  4 drwxrwxr-x 3 user user  4096 Oct  1 18:33 /var/tmp/pear-build-userttUJNa/install-geoip-1.0.8/usr
265362  4 drwxrwxr-x 3 user user  4096 Oct  1 18:33 /var/tmp/pear-build-userttUJNa/install-geoip-1.0.8/usr/lib64
265363  4 drwxrwxr-x 3 user user  4096 Oct  1 18:33 /var/tmp/pear-build-userttUJNa/install-geoip-1.0.8/usr/lib64/php
265409  4 drwxrwxr-x 3 user user  4096 Oct  1 18:33 /var/tmp/pear-build-userttUJNa/install-geoip-1.0.8/usr/lib64/php/5.6
265444  4 drwxrwxr-x 2 user user  4096 Oct  1 18:33 /var/tmp/pear-build-userttUJNa/install-geoip-1.0.8/usr/lib64/php/5.6/modules
265358 68 -rwxr-xr-x 1 user user 67772 Oct  1 18:33 /var/tmp/pear-build-userttUJNa/install-geoip-1.0.8/usr/lib64/php/5.6/modules/geoip.so
```

So, I should be able to find my `geoip.so` at `/var/tmp/pear-build-userttUJNa/install-geoip-1.0.8/usr/lib64/php/5.6/modules/geoip.so`, right?

```
$ ls -al /var/tmp/pear-build-userttUJNa/install-geoip-1.0.8
ls: cannot access /var/tmp/pear-build-userttUJNa/install-geoip-1.0.8: No such file or directory
$ ls -al /var/tmp/pear-build-userttUJNa
ls: cannot access /var/tmp/pear-build-userttUJNa: No such file or directory
```

WRONG!

Where is the .so that the `build` step claims to create? The file is no where on this machine.
The only way I've been able to get the damn .so has been by running the `install` command, but *this* isn't the machine that needs the module.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Update:***
A little more Googling turned up with the answer. I'm using `geoip` here as an example because it is what I'm working with, but you can pretty much use this for any extension with little to no modification.

1. `pecl download geoip-1.0.8` to download the source (or other extension, or other version)
2. `pecl bundle geoip` to extract the extension source
3. `cd geoip && phpize` switch to the source dir and create the autoconf scripts
4. `./configure --prefix=/home/user/rpmbuild/blah --exec-prefix=/home/user/rpmbuild/bleh` to configure
5. `make` the `.so` is in the `modules` directory now
6. Profit!

***This is the old, hacky method:***

What seems to work (for now) is to run the build step so that the downloaded module is populated with the `configure` script, switch to the module directory and run `configure --prefix=some_local_dir` and then run `make`.
Now I can actually see the `geoip.so` file, but it feels like a trick/workaround than an actual solution.